# API Login_check doesn't have Header and I don't know how to put 'Allow-Cross-Origin' without nginx

Tags: angular, symfony, jwt

My problem is that it works with postman but in Angular don't! I read that I have to put

`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:4200'`

but I can't because the controller is not mine, It is an internal symfony controller

Could I overwrite it? Can I put fixed headers to all my controllers ?

I have the followin security.yaml

````
 # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
 password_hashers:
     Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
 # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
 providers:
     # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
     app_user_provider:
         entity:
             class: App\Entity\Usuario
             property: email
     # Usuario con autenticación para la API
     
 firewalls:            
     login:
         pattern:  ^/api/login
         stateless: true
         json_login:
             check_path: /api/login_check
             success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
             failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
         http_basic: ~

     api:
         pattern:   ^/api
         stateless: true
         jwt: ~
     
     dev:
         pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
         security: false

     main:
         lazy: true
         provider: app_user_provider
        
                     
 # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
 # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
 access_control:
     # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
     - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
     - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
 security:
     password_hashers:
         # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
         # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
         # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
         # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
         Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
             algorithm: auto
             cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
             time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
             memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure nelmio_cors.yaml ?

For example, this is mine :

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': null
```

Then in your .env

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$'
```

This way you allow request from localhost:4200
If it dosnt work, try to write it without regex to be sure.
I advise you to take a look at https://symfony.com/bundles/NelmioCorsBundle/current/index.html also to improve your general knowledge

Comment: I try it but my angular client still say " 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Do you know how to send that header with my symfony generated response? 
I see in postman that there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header still

Comment: Finally I put 'aplication/json' in headers of my Angular post and it works

Comment: Do you mean, it was the original problem or it was my solution + adding the proper header in Angular ? Asking for futur reader :)

Comment: + i recommend to use axios as api caller for angular, so you can setup your call much easier.

Comment: the solution was to put 'aplication/json' in headers before sending apart of your given solution. Regards